# Separate data with time series

Tags: python, file, datetime, time-series

I have a data file. It has a start time and end time in `col[2] col[3]`. I want to separate the data that started day1time and ends in day2time. I can separate the data with start day1time and also ending day2time very well. But I am not able to get in-between data. I did try to find some python document to work with time series. I do not happen to find any near by solutions to make any start, that is why I am not able to write any code.

Input Data:

```
1001 747 4575151 4579105
1001 242 4575151 4579105
1001 40 4575151 4579105
1001 492 4575151 4579105
1001 969 4575151 4579105
5153 3200 4575408 4579983
5075 3200 4575408 4653264
4992 3200 4575408 4653264
4916 3200 4575408 4653264
4912 3200 4575408 4593935
4853 3200 4575408 4653264
```

The above col[2] is the start time and col[3] is end time. In few rows both start and end on same day but in few rows they start on day1 and end on day2. I need to separate that type of data.

For Example: From the above input

```
1001 747 4575151 4579105
```

The start timeepoch(col[2]) and stop timeepoch(col[3]) both fall in same day

```
5075 3200 4575408 4653264
```

The start timeepoch is day1 and the stop timeepoch is day2
I need to pull all these rows to separate output files each with pair of Day1 and Day2. The name of those files can be date(day1)_date(day2).

Comment: Have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html)

Comment: If you want a better response, make the phrase "I want to separate the data that started day1time and ends in day2time" more clear. Even if you can't write code, Give an example not only of the input you have, but also the expected output. It is very difficult to tell what exactly you're trying to do.

Comment: Edited the question with some more details